# Limit if the limit is a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can MMA find limits if the limit can be expressed as a function?

Example:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} =\sqrt\frac{x}{2}=\infty$$
$\\\\$

`Limit[Gamma[(x + 1)/2] / Gamma[x/2], x -> ∞]`

returns $\infty$  but I am interested also in the more detailed answer $\sqrt\frac{x}{2}$.

So far only in case I presume the answer I could check if it's true:

`Limit[Gamma[(x + 1)/2] / Gamma[x/2] - Sqrt[x/2], x -> ∞]` returns $0$.

Comment: Maybe: `Series[Gamma[1/2 + x/2]/Gamma[x/2], {x, Infinity, 0}]`?

Answer (score 9):

```
Asymptotic[Gamma[(x + 1)/2]/Gamma[x/2], x -> ∞]
```

> `Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]`

Or

```
Series[Gamma[(x + 1)/2]/Gamma[x/2], x -> ∞]
```

Comment: These variants work only in a newer MMA version.

Comment: @granularbastard : I agree with your comment.  I disagree that it is relevant -- the Question gives no M'ma version constraint and is not tagged with any of the various version tags.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to user Mariusz Iwaniuk the answer can be found easily:

`Series[Gamma[1/2 + x/2]/Gamma[x/2], {x, Infinity, 0}]` returns

$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2x}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

and the 2 right terms vanish in the limit.